# Tool that can convert JavaScript so that it can be embedded in (X)HTML without changes?

Tags: open-source, javascript, html, source-code

I am looking for an open-source tool that accepts JavaScript code and outputs code that is syntactically and semantically equivalent, but can be embedded in HTML and/or XHTML without changes.

This involves the following changes:

- Replace `<!--` with either

  - if in a string or regex literal, then escape one or more of the characters (say to `<\x21--`)
  - if not in a string or regex literal, insert a space (say to `< !--`)
- Replace `</script` with

  - in a string literal, the sequence `\x3c/script`
  - in a regex literal, `</ script` (the `/` terminates the regex)
- Replace `]]>` with

  - in a string or regex literal, `]]\x3e` or other equivalent
  - otherwise, with `]] >` or other equivalent
- Finally, surround the script with `/*<![CDATA[*/` or similar at the start and `/*]]>*/` at the end

This is non-trivial because JavaScript cannot be tokenized without parser feedback.